# Django-Import-Export assign Field to specific column

Tags: python, django, excel, django-import-export

I have a working form which exports all data to xls using Resource and Fields from the django-import-export package. But now I need to go a bit further and make it a bit more advanced. I need to export all data to an existing Excel template, assigning each field to a specific column, as in, for instance: Field 1 needs to be filled in B3, Field 2 in C4 etc. etc.

I'm thinking `after_export()` can be used here but the docs dont go into detail how to use this method. Does anyone have some experience with this package?

I'm not using the admin integration.

Answer (score 0):

`after_export()` is a method you can override to modify data before it is returned.

It does nothing by default.  However, it supplies the `data` object, which is a [Dataset](https://tablib.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) instance.  If you access the `dict` property, then you will have a list of `OrderedDict` instances corresponding to each row which is returned by your queryset.  Therefore, you can construct an entirely new Dataset (list of dicts) which match up with the format you need.

For example, if you wanted the first column of the first row to appear in cell B3, you could do it like this:

```py
    def after_export(self, queryset, data, *args, **kwargs):
        newdata = tablib.Dataset()
        cell1_val = data.dict[0].get("col1", "")
        for i, row in enumerate(data):
            if i == 1:
                newrow = list(row)
                # cell b3
                newrow[2] = cell1_val
                row = newrow
            newdata.append(row)
        data.dict = newdata.dict
```

However, you'll note that this approach is not easy to read and is quite unwieldy.  Therefore if you don't need any other features of `django-import-export` then using a library like [openpyxl](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) is probably a better approach.